# Numpy log10 function: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log10'

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

```
import numpy as np
import astropy as ap

def mass(FWHM, lumi):
    abs_lumi = bhm.L_1450(lumi)
    s1 = (FWHM/1000)
    s2 = ((abs_lumi)/(10**44))
    s = [(s1**2)*(s2**0.53)]
    #mass = np.log10((s1**2)*(s2**0.53)) + 6.66 #old way, didn't work
    mass = np.log10(s) + 6.66
    return mass
```

I'm trying to use the numpy log10 function, but I keep getting an error that reads:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log10'
```

I tried putting my argument into a list (s variable), but I got the same error message. FWHM and lumi are both numbers with decimal points (I think they're called floating point numbers).

Comment: what is `bhm`? Why do you tag and import astropy? It's not used anywhere. What _exactly_ is your input (make it reproduciple)? If I ignore the `bhm.L_1450` call and just use `lumi` everything works fine with integers, floats and arrays. What numpy version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this is a bit tricky and requires a bit of knowledge how Python handles integers and how numpy coerces types. Thanks @ali_m for your comment!

Assuming 64 bit integer the biggest representable integer is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types)) which is roughly `10**19`. But Python falls back to unlimited integer representations as soon as this value is exceeded (like in your case `10**44`). But this unlimited precision type is not nativly supported by NumPy, so results will fall back to `object`s and these `object` arrays **don't** support all (any?) ufuncs, like `np.log10`.

The solution is simple: Convert this large number to a floating point number:

```
>>> # Negative powers will result in floats: 44 -> -44, * instead of /
>>> np.array([10, 20]) * 10**-44
array([  1.00000000e-43,   2.00000000e-43])

>>> # you could also make the base a float: 10 -> 10.
>>> np.array([10, 20]) / 10.**44
array([  1.00000000e-43,   2.00000000e-43])

>>> # or make the exponent a float: 44 -> 44.
>>> np.array([10, 20]) / 10**44.
array([  1.00000000e-43,   2.00000000e-43])

>>> # manually cast the result to a float
>>> np.array([10, 20]) / float(10**44)
array([  1.00000000e-43,   2.00000000e-43])

>>> # not working, result is an object array which cannot be used for np.log10
>>> np.array([10, 20]) / (10**(44))
array([1e-43, 2e-43], dtype=object)
>>> #                       ^---------that's the problem!
```

All you need is to change the third line in your function:

```
import numpy as np

def mass(FWHM, lumi):
    s1 = FWHM / 1000
    s2 = lumi * 10**-44   # changed line, using the first option.
    s = s1**2 * s2**0.53
    mass = np.log10(s) + 6.66
    return mass
```

This works at least with all my test inputs, for example:

```
>>> mass(np.array([10., 20]), np.array([10., 20]))
array([-20.13      , -19.36839411])
```

Comment: I think the issue is related to the fact that `(10**(44))` yields an integer that is too large to be represented by any of numpy's integer dtypes. `np.array(10**44)` is an `np.object` array, containing a native Python integer. `np.iinfo(np.int64).max == 9223372036854775807`, which is only about 10¹⁹. If the exponentiation is performed on floats rather than ints then you will get an `np.float64` array instead - `np.array(10.0**44.0).dtype == np.float64`. Likewise, if the exponent is negative then you will, of course, get a float result.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the problem is as explained above. One simple solution is to convert the type of array using `.astype()`.

```
any_np_array = []
any_np_array = any_np_array.astype(float)
```